# get value from json callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flickr

I am not trying to append flickr photos to my webpage. I am trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude values from the json call back.

This is the code I have so far. Nothing happens when I load it into my browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flickr Pie Chart</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#driver").click(function(event){
            var apiKey = '[YOUR API KEY]';
            var url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=' + apiKey +'&per_page=500&tags=losangeles&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags&format=json&jsoncallback=?';

            $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                //loop through the results with the following function
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                    var geoData +='latitude:' item.latitude + '' + '<br>';
                    geoData += '' + item.longitude;
                    $('#results').append(geoData);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "results"></div>
    <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are binding a click event, but it doesn't appear your code is in a jquery ready handler. Is this what your code actually looks like in the page source?

Comment: Nevermind, I see you edited your post.

Comment: `' + API KEY +'` I think you should put in your variable `apiKey` and you should probably.. you know.. have an API key..

Comment: Check your error console.

Comment: `var geoData += 'latitude:'` <- really, adding to a variable you just created. This code is full of syntax errors !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BtF5H/

Comment: I put in 'api key' for posting on the web. My actual code has the real api key.

Comment: Are you getting anything back from the api call regardless of what happens on the page? What do you see for the request in the network section of the dev tools for the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=
```

Should be

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=
```

But the respond you will get is

```
<rsp stat="fail"><err code="3" msg="Parameterless searches have been disabled. Please use flickr.photos.getRecent instead."/>
```

Which is telling you to use flickr.photos.getRecent

Comment: flickr.photos.getRecent is not the method I want because it does not pull the geo data. I need to use the method flickr.photos.search

Comment: Also changing the &method to ?method did not do anything. When I load the html file into my browser, it is still unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. One of the problems is that I had jsoncallback=? which was returning a jsonp file with a syntax error, it was not returning json. I found the error on the jsonlint.com website. The error had jsonFlickrApi({ at the beginning of the file. I added &nojsoncallback=1 after &format=json and everything worked fine. I also declared my geoData variable before assigning values.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flickr Pie Chart</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var latitude;
var longitude;

var geoData;


$(document).ready(function(){

  var apiKey = '[YOUR API KEY]';
  var url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key='+ apiKey + '&tags=losangeles&has_geo=1&extras=geo,tags&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';

$.getJSON(url, function(data){

//loop through the results with the following function
$.each(data.photos.photo, function(i,item){

  geoData += 'latitude' + ':' + item.latitude + '' + '<br>';
  geoData += 'longitude' + ':' + item.longitude;

$('#results').append(geoData);


});

});

});

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id = "results"></div>
</body>

</html>
```